# Gamma regression only intercept

Tags: python, r, regression, glm

I am new to python I am trying to do a gamma regression, I hope to obtain similar estimations to R, but I can not understand the syntax of python and it generates an error, some idea of how to solve it.

**My R code:**

```
set.seed(1)
y = rgamma(18,10,.1)
print(y)
[1]  76.67251 140.40808 138.26660 108.20993  53.46417 110.61754 119.11950 113.57558  85.82045  71.96892
[11]  76.81693  86.00139  93.62010  69.49795 121.99775 114.18707 125.43608 120.63640

# Option 1
model = glm(y~1,family=Gamma)
summary(model)

# Option 2
# x = rep(1,18)
# summary(glm(y~x,family=Gamma))
```

**Output:**

```
summary(model)

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ 1, family = Gamma)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-0.57898  -0.24017   0.07637   0.17489   0.34345  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.009856   0.000581   16.96 4.33e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Gamma family taken to be 0.06255708)

    Null deviance: 1.1761  on 17  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1.1761  on 17  degrees of freedom
AIC: 171.3

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

**Python Code**

```
y = [76.67251,140.40808,138.26660,108.20993,53.46417,110.61754,
 119.11950,113.57558,85.82045,71.96892,76.81693,86.00139,
 93.62010,69.49795,121.99775,114.18707,125.43608,120.63640]

x = np.repeat(1,18)

import numpy
import statsmodels.api as sm

model = sm.GLM(x,y, family=sm.families.Gamma()).fit()
print(model.summary())
```

I expected an output similar to R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the order of your x and y variables in the python code, then you will see exactly the same results (though the number of significant digits displayed in the output is different from the output in R:

```
 sm.GLM(y,x, family=sm.families.Gamma()).fit().summary()

<class 'statsmodels.iolib.summary.Summary'>
"""
                 Generalized Linear Model Regression Results
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                   18
Model:                            GLM   Df Residuals:                       17
Model Family:                   Gamma   Df Model:                            0
Link Function:          inverse_power   Scale:                 0.0625558699706
Method:                          IRLS   Log-Likelihood:                -83.656
Date:                Sun, 20 May 2018   Deviance:                       1.1761
Time:                        17:59:04   Pearson chi2:                     1.06
No. Iterations:                     4
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          0.0099      0.001     16.963      0.000       0.009       0.011
==============================================================================
"""
```

Various python packages have their own syntax. Here is a nice link with some examples how to use formula syntax in Python:
http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/example_formulas.html[enter link description here](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/example_formulas.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked. I would like to know if in general pyhton you can enter the model type formula ie `y ~ x`?

Comment: @RafaelDíaz HiRafael, I just added a link at the end of my answer. See if it helps. Also if this answers your question, please check "accept" answer. Thank you.

Comment: In R glm() use "Identity" as link function but in your answer Python provides inverse_power in summary. why?

Answer (score 1):

This would be another way using formula, for this you need to import `statsmodels.formula.api`

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

y = [76.67251,140.40808,138.26660,108.20993,53.46417,110.61754,
 119.11950,113.57558,85.82045,71.96892,76.81693,86.00139,
 93.62010,69.49795,121.99775,114.18707,125.43608,120.63640]

df = pd.DataFrame({'y':y})

model = smf.glm(formula = 'y ~ 1', data = df, family=sm.families.Gamma()).fit()
model.summary()
<class 'statsmodels.iolib.summary.Summary'>
"""
                 Generalized Linear Model Regression Results                  
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                   18
Model:                            GLM   Df Residuals:                       17
Model Family:                   Gamma   Df Model:                            0
Link Function:          inverse_power   Scale:                        0.062556
Method:                          IRLS   Log-Likelihood:                -83.656
Date:                Sun, 20 May 2018   Deviance:                       1.1761
Time:                        22:00:54   Pearson chi2:                     1.06
No. Iterations:                     6   Covariance Type:             nonrobust
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept      0.0099      0.001     16.963      0.000       0.009       0.011
==============================================================================
"""
```